# Getting syntax error while running newman on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, postman, newman

I am new to newman. I exported my collection.json and env.json and am trying to integrate with my CI\CD pipeline (vsts in this case).
I have two taks - install newman & then run tests.
Newman installation works fine  but the task of running the test fails with syntax error.

```
newman run Dev-.postman_collection.json -e Dev.postman_environment.json
 ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
 [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /vsts/agent/_work/_temp/5260102a-45bf-435f-814a-110329173b47.sh
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/bin/newman.js:7
     { Command } = require('commander'),
     ^
 
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
     at startup (node.js:136:18)
     at node.js:966:3
```

Installation steps -

```
apt update
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
apt-get install npm
npm install -g newman
```

Node version = v4.2.6

Newman Version = newman@5.1.2

os = ubuntu

What am I missing here ?

Comment: The "-" in the collection filename looks suspicious. Maybe that´s a typo?
Also, I always put quotation marks around filenames/paths.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the node version. My ubuntu machine was installing an archaic version of node. Once I got v12.* , the issue got resolved.

Comment: Just some steps: 1. Use `nvm ls` to find latest vesrion. 2. Install the latest version. 3. Install `newman` again.